# Login PHP + COOKIE + AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, login

após mais de 20 anos sem programar em PHP, decidi fazer um "sistema" de agendamento de clientes para minha namorada. Porém estou passando por um problema que está me deixando com mais cabelos brancos. (rs)

```js
$("#form_validation").click(function(){
                var username = $("#usuario").val().trim();
                var password = $("#password").val().trim();
                    
                if(username == "" || password == ""){
                    $("#modal_erro1").slideDown();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                   $('#modal_erro1').fadeOut('fast');
                    }, 3000);
                }else{          
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'includes/login.php',
                        type:'post',
                        data:'usuario='+username+'&senha='+password,
                        crossDomain: true,
                        success:function(response){

                            if(response == 1){
                                window.location.href="index.php";
                            }else{
                                $("#modal_erro1").slideDown();
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                   $('#modal_erro1').fadeOut('fast');
                                    }, 3000);
                                    result.innerHTML="";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    
                }
            });
```

```html
<?php
 
    include('../../includes/conect.php');
    
    $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
    $password = $_POST["senha"];
    
    $senha = hash('sha256', $password);
    
        $sql_user = "select id,user,pass from admin where user = '{$usuario}' and pass='{$senha}' limit 1";
        $result_user = $conn->query($sql_user);
                
        if ($result_user->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "1";
            $id_client = $result_user["id"];
            setcookie("id",$id_client,"",'/');
        }else{
            echo "0";
        }
    
        
 mysqli_close($conn);
 
 ?>
```

O que acontece é que não é gravado o Cookie.

E outro fato estranho é que se altero o echo de posição dentro do login.php, a resposta retorna nulo

Alguém poderia me dar um rumo?

Comment: Não é gravado o cookie e certamente o login não é feito. Já confirmou se o login realiza? ele entra dentro desse if?

Comment: Olá @BRABO obrigado pela resposta.

Sim ele entra dentro do if e é feito o login. Testando a página includes/login.php em GET

Answer (score -2):

Ta faltando uma chave no teu js,
depois do $.ajax

Deveria ficar assim:

```
$("#form_validation").click(function(){
            var username = $("#usuario").val().trim();
            var password = $("#password").val().trim();
                
            if(username == "" || password == ""){
                $("#modal_erro1").slideDown();
                setTimeout(function() {
               $('#modal_erro1').fadeOut('fast');
                }, 3000);
            }else{          
                $.ajax({
                    url:'includes/login.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:'usuario='+username+'&senha='+password,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success:function(response){

                        if(response == 1){
                            window.location.href="index.php";
                        }else{
                            $("#modal_erro1").slideDown();
                                setTimeout(function() {
                               $('#modal_erro1').fadeOut('fast');
                                }, 3000);
                                result.innerHTML="";
                             }
                        }
                    }
                });
                
            }
        });
```

Comment: Olá @Cristian Curtinaz obrigado por responder, porém gerou um erro "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list".